# ubuntu ftp 500 OOPS: prctl PR_SET_SECCOMP failed

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, ubuntu-14.04, vsftpd

I have just installed vsftp in my ubuntu 14 server. I have installed vsftp also using `sudo apt-get install` command. then restarted ftp server but it refuse all connection for this error `500 OOPS: prctl PR_SET_SECCOMP failed`
please take a look here .

```
aysael@srv:~$ sudo ftp
ftp> open 127.0.0.1
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
500 OOPS: prctl PR_SET_SECCOMP failed
```

Here is my config file `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
seccomp_sandbox=no
listen=YES
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default)
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.

secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
# This option specifies the location of the RSA key to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

- Linux srv 2.6.32-042stab108.2 #1 SMP Tue May 12 18:07:50 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- vsftpd: version 3.0.2
- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message indicates that the `prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, ...)` call failed.

```c
if (!tunable_seccomp_sandbox)
{
  return;
}

...

ret = prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, 2, &prog, 0, 0);
if (ret != 0)
{
  die("prctl PR_SET_SECCOMP failed");
}
```

It can happen when your kernel does not have the `CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER` enabled.

Quote from the [`prctl` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html):

> **PR_SET_SECCOMP** (since Linux 2.6.23)
>
> Set the secure computing (seccomp) mode for the calling thread, to limit the available system calls. The seccomp mode is selected via `arg2`. (The seccomp constants are defined in `<linux/seccomp.h>`
>
> ...
>
> With `arg2` set to `SECCOMP_MODE_FILTER` (since Linux 3.5) the system calls allowed are defined by a pointer to a Berkeley Packet Filter passed in arg3. This argument is a pointer to `struct sock_fprog`; it can be designed to filter arbitrary system calls and system call arguments. **This mode is available only if the kernel is configured with `CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER` enabled.**

---

You should be able to workaround that by configuring vsftpd not to enable the [seccomp mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp).

Use the `seccomp_sandbox=no` option in the `vsftpd.conf`.

The option does not seem to be documented.

But you seem to have that set already. That might indicate that your `vsftpd.conf` is not being used actually. Or that you did not restart vsftpd since your set the option.

If you have the option really set, you should never get the error message, as you can see in the code snippet above (code of your vsftpd 3.0.2).